# Reparing acer 5520g, restarting over and over

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, reboot

I'm having trouble reparing my friends laptop; acer 5520g.
The problem is: it starts, after 2-3 seconds ; it restarts. And then again, and again...
I found a youtube link; which i tried and it worked tonight.[youtube link with repair procedure](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBy7rOiQw18)
The procedure the guy is trying is really wierd (at least from my amateur point of view).

I would like to know why it works, and is it long time solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflowing works by heating the solder and hopefully restoring any minute connections to, say, capacitors, that have come undone due to mechanical or thermal stress.  You often see this for all sorts of electronics and it's not really that unusual.  It probably won't last forever, but it's better than nothing.